# Font rendering in Azure Bastion

Tags: azure

I'm setting up an Azure infrastructure and the plan is to use Bastion to connect to the virtual machines therein. One problem I have found is that the font rendering in Bastion is far less legible than in standard RDP. Here's an example screenshot of a PowerShell script in Notepad. Are there any settings or tricks to improve the font rendering in Azure Bastion?

[image: screenshot of a PowerShell script in Notepad over Bastion]

Answer (score 1):

The font rendering is entirely controlled by the RDP client settings, which you don't have access to, so there's not much you can do to change that at present.